# CSS assigned to specific elements not working in IE7 down

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer-7

Anyone know why CSS assigned to specific elements would stop working in IE7 down?

My [Wordpress site](https://gwca.org) works and looks the same in just about everything except IE7,6,5 and I recently discovered that all of the styles that are assigned to a specific element like `img` `body` or `html` are simply not being supported...

It's really starting to drive me crazy because I can't find anyone out there that has had similar issue... I'm wondering if I'll just have to remove them all and find other ways to make it work.

Anyone have an idea? I really appreciate it

Comment: Can you point to a specific rule that's not being run? Older IE hands CSS Comments weird and you may be messing it up. Or it could be some @ syntax. Or it could be something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo on line 20 of the following style sheet:

https://www.gwca.org/wp-content/themes/GreatWall/style.css

```
.www_FlowSlider_com-branding {
    display:none !important;
    right:1000px !important;
    width:0px !important;
    height:0px !important'; <-- that random single quote.
}
```

Comment: I've seen that break a declaration, but not the remaining declarations of the stylesheet. The line you're pointing to is #1 in the CSS. Surely, he'd complain of more than just `body, html, img` to be broken.

Comment: @Dawson weird quirk of IE7, you can test it here: http://jsbin.com/owisaq/3 ... switch around between IE7 and 8 within IE's dev tools in IE10.

Comment: Nice catch on the typo. FF/Chrome just throw that line (and sometimes those that follow) out.

Comment: Wow, thats insane something so small could destroy a whole stylesheet. Thank you Andre

Answer (score 1):

Those are called inline style rules.  They *are* working in IE7 for me. It is not uncommon to see rendering differences especially in IE5-7 because they are not very standards-compliant versions of the browser.

The problem I saw was related to relative positioning.  I would suggest reading up on the different types of positioning and also the rendering differences of earlier version of Internet Explorer. I usually check IE7 incrementally during development.

Another strange quirk with the earlier versions of IE is that some elements won't display properly unless you trigger IE's proprietary property called `hasLayout` using the CSS rule `zoom: 1;`